# Bootstrap 3 dropdown closes when I click away

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So consider the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdownMenu1').attr('aria-expanded', true);
    $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    $('#dropdownMenu1').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

This is a legacy app that I am maintaining and the bootstrap dropdown menu has to stay open.

When the page loads, I achieve what I want. However when I click anywhere on the page the drop down closes.

Is this not the correct way to keep it open when the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hide.bs.dropdown`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#dropdowns-events) event like so:

```js
$('#dropdownMenu1').addClass('open');
$('#dropdownMenu1').on({
  "hide.bs.dropdown": function() {
    return $(this).attr('closable') == 'true';
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```